# can't find file in terminal

Tags: search, terminal, directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPsDl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLCpO.png)

hello!
i can see the file but terminal can't find the file
as you can see, i can see the file when i put 'ls'. but can't move to the file on terminal.

i uploaded the files on github utill two days ago
but today i can't ..ㅠㅠ.....

maybe i guess the reason is i installed postman yesterday and maybe i don't know but some complexity goes on in the back of my computer..?

can i possibly know the way to move to the file on terminal? and why it doesn't work..?

searching for similer problem but there isn't..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your directory by " for example:

```
cd "mini projects"
```

Comment: thank you!! it works!! but can i ask you why..? i always cd mini projects and it worked. and now i have to wrap, and don't know why ㅠㅠ..

Comment: As far as I know, it should not work; maybe you are doing something wrong, besides you can use this mode as well `cd mini\ projects/`